# Data win Bind style properties winJS

Tags: winjs

How to bind Style Properties in winJS ? ?

```
<div  data-win-bind="background: bindingClass;">
```

this doesnt seem to work
But

```
<div data-win-bind="innerHTML: bindtext;">
```

This seem to work even `textContent` seem to Bind.

Comment: Binding always happens on the element where you declare data-win-bind. This means that you reference properties as if you were doing so in JavaScript. A div has an innerHTML property directly; background, however, as you see in the other response, is always referenced through style.background. This has nothing to do with WinJS--it's simply how you get to properties through HTML element object in JS, and WinJS doesn't mess with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice one . Clear topic winJs :)

Here's the code

```
<div data-win-bind="style.background: bindingColor; innerHTML : bindingText">
```

So both can be accomodated :)